# Почему css анимация работает не корректно?

Tags: html, css, css-animation

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: 0.6s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.wrapper:hover .back {
  display:block;
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
  transition: 3s;
}

.back {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="front">
    <img src="http://www.sluniverse.com/200.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4b/Little_island_colour_logo_200x200.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Когда убираешь курсор, анимация не возвращается меняется обратно, да и при самом наведении как-то некорректно отображается.

Answer (score 3):

У вас есть несколько ошибок:

1) `transition` у вас проставлен только на `:hover`. Соответственно, когда вы убираете курсор мыши, он проставляется в значение по умолчанию — ноль. Поэтому и анимации скрытия обратно нет.

2) У вас на `.back` стоит `display: none`. Так что даже если анимация скрытия обратно и была бы, то её не было бы видно, потому что `.back` скрывается сразу после того, как вы убираете курсор; свойство `display` нельзя анимировать.

3) Вы вращаете `.wrapper`. Когда он вращается, он может сбежать из-под курсора мыши, из-за чего `:hover` прекратит работать, анимация отменится и пойдёт обратно — в общем, будет глючить так или иначе в зависимости от браузера.

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, вы хотите поворачивать некую карточку на 180 градусов при наведении курсора мыши и поворачивать обратно при уведении курсора. С учётом вышенаписанных ошибок я предлагаю такой вариант: никаких `display`, вращаем только `.front` и `.back`, `transition` прописываем без `:hover`, а проблемы с пересечением фронта и бэка решаем с помощью `backface-visibility: hidden;`.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front {
  transform:rotateY(0deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.wrapper:hover .front {
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;

  transform:rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.wrapper:hover .back {
  transform:rotateY(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="front">
    <img src="http://www.sluniverse.com/200.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4b/Little_island_colour_logo_200x200.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper {
  perspective: 1000px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.wrapper-inner {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.wrapper:hover .wrapper-inner,
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper-inner">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="http://www.sluniverse.com/200.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4b/Little_island_colour_logo_200x200.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Справа появляется скролл

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi просто `perspective` уберите (но с ним красивее :)